# Removing data attribute on mouseleave

Tags: javascript

I have some navigation links that when hovered over creates a data attribute on the body tag which enables me to add a background color to different links which is exactly what I want however what I'd like is when I hover out of those links the data attribute is removed or a class applied so I can add a default color to the nav links.

here is my html setup:

```
<nav>
    <a href="#">One</a>
    <a href="#">Two</a>
    <a href="#">Three</a>
</nav>

<p class="One">This is class One.</p>
<p class="Two">This is class Two.</p>
<p class="Three">This is class Three.</p>
<p class="One">This is also class One.</p>
<p class="Two">This is also class Two.</p>
<p class="Three">This is also class Three.</p>
```

This is the javascript that sets the data attribute to the body:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){

    var links = document.querySelectorAll("nav a");
    for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
        links[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
            document.querySelector("h1").innerText = this.innerText;
            document.body.setAttribute("data-nav",this.innerText);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The opposite of `mouseover` is `mouseout`.** The example below demonstrates how you can use `data-nav` as a parameter to effect the styling of elements within the body.

I've added a second javascript function adding a `mouseout` event to each of the `nav a` elements, simplying switching `mouseover` to `mouseout`. I have cleared the `data-nav` property and so the CSS styling ceases to apply.

**CSS styling via attributes** can be done using `element[attribute="value"]`, in your case it would be `body[data-nav="Red"]`

It is more appropriate to use classes, but the code below works.

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function(){

    var links = document.querySelectorAll("nav a");
    for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
        links[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
            document.querySelector("h1").innerText = this.innerText;
            document.body.setAttribute("data-nav",this.innerText);
        });
        
        links[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
            document.querySelector("h1").innerText = "No color selected";
            document.body.setAttribute("data-nav","");
        });
    }
});
```

```css
body p {
  color: black;
}

body[data-nav="Red"] p {
  color: red;
}
  
body[data-nav="Blue"] p {
  color: blue;
}
  
body[data-nav="Green"] p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav>

    <a href="#">Red</a>
    <a href="#">Blue</a>
    <a href="#">Green</a>

</nav>

<body>

    <h1>No color selected</h1>
   
    <p class="One">This is class One.</p>
    <p class="Two">This is class Two.</p>
    <p class="Three">This is class Three.</p>
    <p class="One">This is also class One.</p>
    <p class="Two">This is also class Two.</p>
    <p class="Three">This is also class Three.</p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the "[mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover)" event to a "[mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter)" and add a "[mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave)" event.

The "mouseenter" event can set the attribute to what you need, and the "mouseleave" event would remove the attribute.

**Key differences**

> [This website](https://javascript.info/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave) has some good examples and specific differences
>   between mouseover, mouseenter, and mouseleave. Below are take-aways from it.
>
> **mouseover**: The mousemove event triggers when the mouse moves. But that doesn’t mean that every pixel leads to an event. The browser
>   checks the mouse position from time to time. And if it notices changes
>   then triggers the events.
>
> **mouseenter**: When the mouseenter triggers, it doesn’t matter where it goes while inside the element.
>
> **mouseleave**: The mouseleave event only triggers when the cursor leaves it.

I recommend using CSS (not JavaScript) to define a style on the links themselves on hover if you're changing the styling of the link being hovered over. If you're changing the styling of the links not being hovered over you can still use a class instead of a data attribute, but either will work. A bit more description of your specific use case could help me make this answer more robust.

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpe5vobg/1/)

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    var links = document.querySelectorAll("nav a");
    for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
        links[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){
            document.querySelector("h1").innerText = this.innerText;
            document.body.setAttribute("data-nav",this.innerText);
        });
        links[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
            document.body.setAttribute("data-nav", '');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some best practices:

- Don't add listener for each elements. Instead of this, add a global listener or add one listener for some parent of your elements.
- Use class-name selector instead of tag-name selector (`.h1` instead `h1`)

My example:

```js
/** Helper for toggle classNames of body. */
function toggleHoverClass (className) {
  // Remove all hover-classes.
  document.body.classList.remove('hover-1', 'hover-2', 'hover-3');
  // Add new hover-class.
  document.body.classList.add(className);
}

window.addEventListener("load",function(){
  var elNav = document.getElementById('nav');
  var elH1 = document.getElementById('h1');
  var defaultH1Value = elH1.innerText;

  // One mouseover handler
  elNav.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
    // If it is link with data-type
    if (event.target.dataset && event.target.dataset.type) {
      elH1.innerText = event.target.innerText;
      // Add hover class
      toggleHoverClass('hover-' + event.target.dataset.type);
    }
  });

  // One mouseout handler
  elNav.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) {
    // If it is link with data-type
    if (event.target.dataset && event.target.dataset.type) {
      elH1.innerText = defaultH1Value;
      // Remove hover class
      document.body.classList.remove('hover-' + event.target.dataset.type);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body.hover-1 .One,
body.hover-2 .Two,
body.hover-3 .Three{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">Hover over the link</h1>

<nav id="nav">
    <a href="#" data-type="1">One</a>
    <a href="#" data-type="2">Two</a>
    <a href="#" data-type="3">Three</a>
</nav>

<p class="One">This is class One.</p>
<p class="Two">This is class Two.</p>
<p class="Three">This is class Three.</p>
<p class="One">This is also class One.</p>
<p class="Two">This is also class Two.</p>
<p class="Three">This is also class Three.</p>
```